# "resource script" opens like a folder?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resource-files

I am new to creating desktop apps, and I have been following a tutorial, which mentions creating a "resource file." However, when I follow instructions for creating such a file, it creates something which opens like a folder. The tutorial seems quite old (I found things relating to it from 2008) and so I don't know if something has changed since then. I am using Visual Studio 2019. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A resource script is a text file with the .rc extension. Its representation in VS IDE is a folder, as it indeed contains other resources. [This MSDN post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-create-a-resource-script-file?view=vs-2019) has more details.

Comment: [About Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) has everything you need to know. Regarding resource files, nothing has significantly changed since Windows 3.1. It's still the same syntax, still needs to be compiled using rc.exe, and its output still needs to be linked into the final exectuable.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. I didn’t see the part about opening it as a text file, but I know what to do now. Thank you.

Comment: You can right-click on the resource file in the solution explorer and use the "View Code" command to get that script into a text editor window.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was unclear. I meant that I had just found that part and I had not seen it earlier.